# How to fetch string in particular key in firebase

Tags: iphone, firebase, firepad

I have firebase data as below:

```
chats
| 
|
+ - - -simplelogin48simplelogin50
|    
|     
|
+ - - simplelogin50simplelogin48 
|
|     
|   
+ - - -simplelogin48simplelogin50
```

Now I want to fetch chat data which contains "simplelogin 48". Is it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Firebase does not support a contains operator in its queries. Firebase provides `queryStartingAtValue` and `queryEndingAtValue` operators for selecting a range of keys, but they are both based on the start of the key (or property value or priority if you've ordered on those). See this section of the Firebase iOS documentation that explains querying.

So by:

```
[[[[ref queryOrderedByKey] queryStartingAtValue:@"simplelogin48"] queryEndingAtValue:@"simplelogin48"]
```

You would get:

```
+ - - -simplelogin48simplelogin50
+ - - -simplelogin48simplelogin50
```

But **not**:

```
+ - - simplelogin50simplelogin48
```

The way to work around this is by creating a so-called *index node*, which in this case simply lists the chat ids for each user:

```
chats_by_user
  |    
  + - - simplelogin48
  |  |     
  |  + - - simplelogin48simplelogin50 
  |  |     
  |  + - - simplelogin48simplelogin49 
  |  |     
  |  + - - simplelogin50simplelogin48 
  |    
  + - - simplelogin49
  |  |     
  |  + - - simplelogin48simplelogin49 
  |    
  + - - simplelogin50
    |     
    + - - simplelogin50simplelogin48 
    |     
    + - - simplelogin48simplelogin50
```

With this structure you can simply access `chats_by_user/simplylogin48` to get all references to all chats for that user.

Comment: @ Frank van Puffelen i had one doubt for example when "simplelogin48 " user is chatting with "simple login 50 " the chat data need to update under  both users in " chats_by_user ",if so we are replicating same data twice is its good approach.

Comment: A good approach is the one that works for all your use-cases. But in general it is quite normal to denormalize some of your data ina NoSQL database. For a general explanation see this blog post: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html . Don't focus too much on the Firebase API used in the post, that has been expanded considerably since then (a.o. to allow ordering and filtering on child properties).